# Kendo Dropdown list - remote data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui

I have local service and I want bind data to dropdown list. When my dd list downloads data got me error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token:

Any Idea how fix that ?

My JSON:

```
{"Data":{"Data":[{"__type":"EType:#DataAccessLayer.Entities","Id":1,"Name":"Zamestnanec"},{"__type":"EType:#DataAccessLayer.Entities","Id":2,"Name":"Manažér"}]},"Valid":true}
```

my kendo ddl:

```
$("#types").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Data.Data.Name",
            dataValueField: "Data.Data.Id",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        url: "http://localhost:3992/MyService.svc/GetRoleTypes",
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for your example the same ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the response before dropdown can use it, you can parse response using schema option in data source, like this :

```
$("#types").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "http://localhost:3992/MyService.svc/GetRoleTypes"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (response) {
                return response.Data.Data;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and done forget to change dataTextField and dataValueField also as shown above

Comment: still same issues :/ ... unexpected token :

Comment: still that same :/ I try validate json in online tool but it looks okej :/ ... now I try call this service only in jQ ajax and in success method print result and same error with unexpected ":"